# Displaying a CBitmap on a CHtmlView

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to draw on top of a CHtmlView. I tried overriding OnDraw() but I end up with either some Unhandled exception or nothing being drawn. Any tips or recommendations?  Our documents contain a .bmp zipped inside the document and I am trying to display those images on to the CHtmlView.

Here's what I started on ***(reference: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?255739-Bitmaps-in-CHtmlView)***, just trying to use the pen to see if anything comes up:

```
void CMyHtmlView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);

IOleWindow* InterfacePtr;
HWND hwnd;

// long pointer to Idispatch interface
LPDISPATCH DispatchPtr;

// receives pointer to Idispatch
DispatchPtr = GetHtmlDocument();

// InterfacePtr now contains IOleWindow*
DispatchPtr->QueryInterface(IID_IOleWindow, (void**)&InterfacePtr);

// get the window handle
InterfacePtr->GetWindow(&hwnd);

// get dc from hwnd
CClientDC dc((CWnd*)hwnd);

CPen* Pen = new CPen;
Pen->CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3 ,RGB(0, 0, 0));
dc.SelectObject(Pen);
dc.MoveTo(100,100);
dc.LineTo(300,300);

}
```

Setting the CClientDC may be part of the issue

Comment: You can insert jpeg or png files directly in to HTML source

Comment: This page seems to be headed in the right direction: (http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/12037601/BItmap-Display-in-CHtmlView.html) Now just researching how to draw a CDib on top of an existing resource if that is possible.

Comment: Why do you have to do it that way? You can draw bitmap on your own client DC, or you can insert jpeg/png in HTML source of the HTML control, you can put it as HTML background, header image or whatever...